# Sending an existing record details to a new record to save time - "I did this workout too"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've created a Ruby on Rails app where users can record and share their workouts. I am wondering how to allow a user to 'clone' a workout so to speak, saving the time it would take to copy and paste, or enter the workout themselves.

My idea is that when a current_user sees a workout that they also did (i.e. 100 pushups, 100 situps...etc.) they can click a link that says `I did this workout too`. That link would take them to /views/workouts/new but carry with it the workout title and description from where the link was clicked, pre populating the receiving fields.

The workout table has :title and :description. An ideas on how to do this?

UPDATE:

Adding a little more detail here. So If I am showing `workout A`, which has a title of `Workout A title` and a description of `this is a great workout`. I want the user to click a link that sends to `new_workout_path` and sends with it the title and description to pre populate the `f.textfield :title` and `f.textarea :description`. Such that the new workout form has `Workout A Title` and `this is a great workout` in the description textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a nice way to do this using the `clone` method for ActiveRecord objects.

Something like this in your controller:

```
def new
  if params[:cloned_workout]
    workout_to_clone = Workout.find params[:cloned_workout]
    @workout = workout_to_clone.clone
  else
    @workout = Workout.new
  end
  # Any other new related setup can be put here
end
```

Now you can have a link like this in the view:

```
<%= link_to "I did this too", new_workout_url + "?cloned_workout=#{@workout.id}" %>
```

(Note: that link_to line could be written better)

Comment: quick follow up...any way I can have condition in the view that keys on whether the workout is being cloned or not? `<% unless workout.clone...%>` type thing.

Comment: Ah, just figured it out. `<% unless params[:cloned_workout].blank? %>`

Comment: In this use case `clone` is not the ideal method to use. Please use `dup` instead. `http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Core/clone`

Answer (score 5):

You can copy all the attributes of an ActiveRecord model from one to another, like so:

```
workout = Workout.find(params[:id])
new_workout = Workout.new workout.attributes
```

In this example, we pull the existing workout out of the database (using the params hash like a controller action would), then use its attributes to initialize the new workout.

Comment: I like this one as I don't have to worry about the id being dupped or cloned into the new record.