# Rails form - edit and resubmit form as new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails site with a long form on it, users want to edit one of their old submitted forms, edit a few details then resubmit it as a new entry, I'm unsure of how to go about this.

Should this be a separate controller action or can I use the current controllers edit action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the ActiveRecord `clone` method as descibed in the answer here;

[Sending an existing record details to a new record to save time - "I did this workout too"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372889/sending-an-existing-record-details-to-a-new-record-to-save-time-i-did-this-wo)